# Solving a Quadratic Equation with Trigonometric Variables

Tags: trigonometry, roots, quadratics

After referring to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858415/solving-a-quadratic-trigonometric-equation), I tried a similar approach to solve the below and got an incorrect answer.

> Find the values of $p$ so that the equation $2\cos^2x - (p+3)\cos\ x + 2(p-1) = 0$ has real roots.

The solution to the question (given in the answer section of the book I referred) is as follows $-$

[image: Solution to Question]

The above solution is correct but, **Why do I need to solve the equation for $\cos(x)$ and then find the values of $p$ instead of just applying $b^2-4ac \ge 0$ to the coefficients of the equations which are $2,\ (p+3)$ and $2(p-1)$ to get the values of $p$ such that the equation has real roots?**

Comment: Your method would have worked for $2 x^2 - (p+3) x + 2(p-1) = 0$ as $x$ can take any real value. But it would not work for quadratic in $\cos x$ as there is an additional constraint of $|\cos x| \leq 1$

Comment: In fact if this had just been an ordinary polynomial in a real variable and not a polynomial of $\cos x,$ you could set $p$ to any real number and you would always have two real solutions, $(p-1)/2$ and $2.$

Comment: So, Does it mean, because of the constraint of $0\le cos\ x \le 1$, directly applying $b^2-4ac\ge 0$ fails?

Comment: @MathLover, I missed to mention you in the above comment.

Comment: @AtheeshThirumalairajan yes that is correct because not all values of $p$ found using $b^2 - 4 ac \geq 0$ will  give roots in $(-1, 1)$. Also a correction: it is $ - 1 \le \cos x \leq 1$

Comment: @AtheeshThirumalairajan No, re-read Math Lover's first comment.  The $(b^2 - 4ac)$ analysis is **necessary but not sufficient**.  You **also** have to consider that $-1 \leq \cos x \leq 1.$  Any value of $p$ that creates $1$ or $2$ real roots, none of which are in the interval $[-1,1]$ would have to be rejected.

Comment: Thank You for helping me solve this question. I also found out that on applying $b^2-4ac \ge 0$ I get a quadratic inequality. I solved the equation assuming $p^2-10p+25=0$ instead of $p^2-10p+25 \ge 0$ (Obtained by applying $b^2-4ac \ge 0$ and simplifying) and so, I got $5$ as the ONLY real root of $p$ which was eliminated as the roots of $p$ need to be in the interval as stated above. I got the correct answer after solving the inequalities and eliminating the values outside the interval.

Comment: That doesn't sound correct at all. You haven't shown any logical connection between anything in that last comment and the actual problem that was to be solved. How can the procedure you described possibly help us know that $-1 \leq p \leq 3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem to be solved was:

> Find the values of $p$ so that the equation $2\cos^2 x - (p+3)\cos x + 2(p-1) = 0$ has real roots.

This is not the same as a problem like finding $p$ such that the equation
$ 2 y^2 - (p+3)y + 2(p-1) = 0 $ has real roots, because we don't just have
a polynomial in some variable $y$; the equation also involves $\cos x$.

When we ask for real roots we are asking for real numbers that can be plugged in for $x$ so as to make the equation $2\cos^2 x - (p+3)\cos x + 2(p-1) = 0$ true.
Now since $x$ must be real, we know $\cos x$ also will be real
(the cosine of any real number is a real number).
More specifically, $\cos x$ will be a real number belonging to the closed interval $[-1,1].$
But it can be any number in that interval; if we let $x$ run from $0$ to $\pi$ then $\cos x$ will hit every number in $[-1,1].$

The thing is, if we have to start worrying about the "interval $[-1,1]$" part right away, it's hard to see how to solve the problem.
So let's just worry about the "real number" part at first.
We want to know that there is a real number that you can put in place of $\cos x$
in the equation that makes the equation true.

Or to put it slightly differently, let's define the variable $y$ by the
relationship $y = \cos x,$ and now we want to know that there is a real number $y$ that satisfies
$$  2 y^2 - (p+3)y + 2(p-1) = 0 . $$

You already know how to do that: you must ensure that $b^2 - 4ac \geq 0.$
In this particular problem,
$$b^2 - 4ac = (p + 3)^2 - 16(p-1) = p^2 - 10p + 25 = (p - 5)^2.$$

Now observe that $(p - 5)^2 \geq 0$, and therefore
$b^2 - 4ac \geq 0,$ for any real number $p.$

That is, for *any* real number $p,$ there is at least one real number, usually two, that could be the value of $y$ in the true equation $ 2 y^2 - (p+3)y + 2(p-1) = 0. $

But now we have to remember that $\cos x$ cannot be just any real number.
It has to be in the interval $[-1,1].$
So instead of just being concerned about whether a real number exists that makes
$ 2 y^2 - (p+3)y + 2(p-1) = 0 $ true when we plug this number in for $y,$
we need to think about *which* real number we might have to plug in for $y,$
and make sure that that number is in the interval $[-1,1].$

The use of the variable $p$ makes it a little difficult to guess a factorization of the polynomial $2 y^2 - (p+3)y + 2(p-1),$ so let's just apply the standard formula to find solutions of any solvable quadratic equation in $y$:

$$ y = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{2a}. $$

Putting $a = 2,$ $b = -(p+3),$ $c = 2(p-1),$ we have

$$ y = \frac{(p+3) \pm \sqrt{(p+3)^2 - 16(p-1)} }{4}
 = \frac{(p+3) \pm (p - 5)}{4}. $$

If we choose $+$ for $\pm$ we get $y = (p - 1)/2$ and if we choose $-$ we get
$y = 2.$

Obviously $y = 2$ is no good because $2$ is not in the interval $[-1,1]$
so it cannot be a value of $\cos x.$
So our only hope is that the solution is $y = (p - 1)/2.$
In order for this to be a value of $\cos x$ (so that it solves the problem that was originally given) it must be true that
$-1 \leq (p - 1)/2 \leq 1.$
The rest of the solution is just algebra to simplify these inequalities.
The simplified version is $-1 \leq p \leq 3.$

---

Now it may seem that the book's solution did not actually start by requiring that
$b^2 - 4ac \geq 0$ and asking what $p$ made that inequality true.
You might ask what allows them to skip that step.
The reason they can do it is because the test for $b^2 - 4ac \geq 0$ is itself
just a consequence of the formula

$$ y = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{2a}. $$

If the expression under the $\sqrt{\phantom{0}}$ symbol is negative then it does not have a real square root and the formula does not give you any solutions.
So that expression has to be *non*-negative, that is, $b^2 - 4ac \geq 0.$
And if all you care about is whether there is *any* solution,
not *what particular number* the solution is, $b^2 - 4ac \geq 0$ is all you need to know, because then there will be a real square root and you'll combine it with other real numbers to get a real number (or two) in the end.

(I'm assuming that you're working in real numbers only and not complex numbers.
If you allow complex numbers then there is a non-real square root and we have to do some extra work to show that the final result of calculating $y$ is not real.)

Since we actually need to know more about $y$ than just that it's a real number,
we need to finish evaluating the formula. In the book's solution they go directly to that step, but while simplifying $\sqrt{(p+3)^2 - 16(p-1)}$ to $\pm(p-5)$
they had to figure out that $(p+3)^2 - 16(p-1) = (p - 5)^2,$
which implies that $b^2 - 4ac \geq 0.$

Comment: +1 : very nice answer.